# PHP - Imagick - Problems converting EPS file

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, vector-graphics, eps

i've got some trouble reading and writing eps files with \Imagick in PHP.

Here's the EPS file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9s8q2p0apyswbg/Logo.eps?dl=0

**The problems**

1) After reading this file and writing it again (saving it with another filename) the images colors are inverted - what the actual fk?

2) Whatever i try, the image wont come out with a better quality. Viewing this image in EpsViewer and changing the width and height (with these two input fields top left) the image sharpens as it should. How can i do this in PHP with Imagick?

**My code (for problem #1 and #2)**

```
<?php
    $IM = new \Imagick();
    $IM->readImage('./file.eps');
    $IM->writeImage('./file2.eps');
    $IM->destroy();
?>
```

But the file is inverted and has really bad quality. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgoasdr43uitypn/Logo2.eps?dl=0

3) The eps file looks different in Adobe Illustrator (purple) and EPSViewer (blue). I think i don't get that vector images thingy ...

I'd really appreciate any help because this vector images arbitrariness is driving me insane. Please don't post any CLI-related commands.

(sorry for bad english, i tried my best)

Comment: Try `setImageResolution(288,288);` **before** reading in the EPS file.

Comment: This won't work because setImageResolution only works after reading an image. setResolution() would work **before** reading the file, but i tried this already and this doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Your EPS is CMYK. That is why it looks reversed when processed. You need to convert it to sRGB. You can do that by setting the density before reading the EPS and by changing the colorspace to sRGB before reading the file or use profiles to convert it after reading the file. Note that ImageMagick (and thus Imagick) are raster processors. When reading a vector file such as EPS it will rasterize it and then put a vector shell about it. ImageMagick is not a good tool to go vector to vector. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#profiles